# Draw triangle on android

Tags: android, react-native

Hello I need to draw a triangle. I use this style

```
  triangle: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',

    borderTopWidth: 20,
    borderRightWidth: 40,
    borderBottomWidth: 20,
    borderLeftWidth: 0,
    borderTopColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: '#FF0000',
    borderBottomColor: 'transparent',
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
  },
```

On IOS it works perfectly. But Android doesn't display anything. I use RN 0.24.1
Can anyone help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
height: 10, 
width: 10, 
transform: [ 
  { rotate: '45deg' }, 
  { translateY: -7 }, 
],
```

It's not the best but it works.

Comment: Works fine as ever

Answer (score 1):

Try this

**Js**

```
var Triangle = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.triangle, this.props.style]} />
    )
  }
})
```

and your **css** would be somewhat like this:

```
triangle: {
    width: 0,
    height: 0,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderLeftWidth: 50,
    borderRightWidth: 50,
    borderBottomWidth: 100,
    borderLeftColor: 'transparent',
    borderRightColor: 'transparent',
    borderBottomColor: 'red'
  }
```

It will give you output like this:

[image: Triangle]

Reference [Shapes in react native](http://browniefed.com/blog/the-shapes-of-react-native/)

Comment: Doesn't work. Draws square on android ... ios is pyramid! I know this references. I did it accordingly

Comment: you may try 'react-art'